# jQuery function not updating to newly added apend elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to append a div when user clicks the button. And this span is a counter that updates the number of count when something is dropped into this box. I am trying to update the count using the following code via ajax but the count does not get updated at the interval. Can anyone figure out where I went wrong?

This code will append the new div when when a button is clicked.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click','#somebutton',function () {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value++;
  document.getElementById('number').value = value;
  $("#table-container-main").append('<div id="'+value+'" class="table-container-individual" table_No="'+value+'"><div id="table-container-header"><div id="table-container-header-title">Table '+value+'</div>  <div id="table-container-header-count"><span id="table-container-header-count-'+value+'"></span><span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Seats Occupied</span></div></div></div>');

});
});
```

This code is supposed to get the table number from using .attr. However the value I get for tableNo is undefined. This value is supposed to be sent to the php file and echo the count. The code works fine if I dont use the .attr from the append.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   setInterval(function(){
  counttable();
},100);
   function counttable(){
   var tableNo = $("#table-container-individual").attr("table_No");
                  $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url:"counttable.php",
                    data:{tableNo:tableNo},
                    success:function(data){
                         $("#table-container-header-count-"+tableNo).html(data);
                    }
                  });
                }
                counttable();
});
```

Please look trough my code and help me with this. Thank you

Comment: Need more context. Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

On click on your button, you are appending a div with class `table-container-individual`.

When trying to access your div, you're targeting an id instead of a class. Use `.` instead of `#` :

```
$(".table-container-individual").attr("table_No");
```

Answer (score 0):

Would advise the following updates to your mixed code.

```js
$(function() {
  function counttable(tci) {
    var tableID = $("#" + tci).data("table-no");
    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "counttable.php",
      data: {
        tableNo: tableID
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $("#table-container-header-count-" + tableNo).html("Seats Occupied: " + data);
      }
    });
  }
  $('#parentDiv').on('click', '.childButton', function(event) {
    var value = $('#table-number').val();
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : parseInt(value);
    value++;
    $('#table-number').val(value);
    var $tblContInd = $("<div>", {
        id: "tci-" + value,
        class: "table-container-individual",
        "data-table-no": value
      })
      .appendTo($("#table-container-main"));
    $("<div>", {
        class: "table-container-header"
      })
      .appendTo($tblContInd);
    $("<div>", {
        class: "table-container-header-title"
      })
      .html("Table " + value)
      .appendTo($tblContInd.find(".table-container-header"));
    $("<div>", {
        class: "table-container-header-count"
      })
      .html("<span id='table-container-header-count-" + value + "'>Seats Occupied</span>")
      .appendTo($tblContInd.find(".table-container-header"));
  });
  $(".table-container-individual").each(function(ind, elem) {
    counttable($(elem).attr("id"));
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="parentDiv">
  <input type="number" id="table-number" value="0" style="width: 2em;" /><button class="childButton">Add Table</button>
</div>
<div id="table-container-main"></div>
```

Where you were using `id` I would switch to `class`. HTML requires each ID to be unique. So a lot of the `div` elements would need to use class to define multiple headers and titles and the like.